# Find one user on moongose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following problem to solve: I have multiple users in a database (mongoDB). Pass the following, in a specific url, for example: **"my-page/users/here-goes-the-name-of-the-user".** When displaying the username in the url, I convert it to lowercase and replace the spaces with hyphens: Husdady Mena ===> /husdady-mena.

In the database, the user names are as shown before converting the name to lowercase, eg: Husdady Mena, Donald Trump, Will Smith, etc.

I need to somehow filter a user, which is in the url as /husdady-mena with the database user: Husdady Mena, in order to obtain his information, how could that filter be done in mongoose?

A clear example with js:

```js
const users = [{ name: 'Husdady Mena' }, {name:'Donald Trump'}, {name:'Will Smith'}, {name:'Dubá Solis'}]

const username = "dubá-solis"
const url = `my-page.com/users/${username}`
const userToFilter = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)

const userFound = users.find(({ name }) => {
  const usernameToLowerCase = name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/gim, "-")
  return userToFilter === usernameToLowerCase
})

console.log(userFound)
```

If the example is not clear to you: I make a request from the frontend to the backend to obtain a specific user, I need to obtain the user by name, it is not necessary to obtain it by id. In the url something like: my-page/users/dubá-solis is painted, I get the name of the user, which is: dubá-solis. in the backend is something like:

```js
// Librarys
const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router()

// Models
const User = require('@models/users/User')

router.get(
  '/users/:username',
  function(req, res) {
    try {
      // req.params.username === "dubá-solis"
      const userFound = await User.findOne({ name: req.params.username })
      // In database, the username is Dubá Solis, that's why it returns me null
      return res.status(200).json(userFound)
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('[UserFound.err]', err)
    }
  }
)

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just convert the username and pass that to the query function? Something like:

```js
const convertUsername = username => {
  const nameParts = username.split('-');
  return nameParts.map(n => n.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + n.slice(1))
    .join(' ');
};

console.log(convertUsername('dubá-Solis'));
console.log(convertUsername('joan-of-arc'));
```

Then, just do `User.findOne({ name: convertUsername(req.params.username) })`

Comment: Interesting answer I had not thought about it, although I must clarify that they will not always see users who have 2 names, there are users with more than 2 names, perhaps that can be easily solved. What worries me is that the usernames are dynamic, they can be like this: Adolf hittler, Joan of Arc, Agustin Laporte. In some cases it will not be necessary to convert to uppercase, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Husdady good point, I modified the code a bit to work with more than 2 names. As for the ones that are already uppercase, you can see from the example that it won't affect the outcome. The only exception is if you expect parts of the names like `'of'` not to be capitalized, in which case you'll have to specify a list of words which won't be capitalized and check each part against it before capitalizing

Comment: I was thinking of doing with regex, a filter, that takes the following letter from a blank space, eg: "My name Is", it would take the 'n', and it would not convert it to uppercase, therefore, I suppose it would be less I work to put a list of words to exclude, if this really doesn't work, I'll take the other into account.